# Bad Syntax error for URI value after JSON serialization

Tags: ios, json, rest, tastypie

For a REST web service call using PUT, I need to send JSON that looks like this:

```
{"leader":"John Smith","leader_id":"asldfkj234234324asldkfs234","resource_uri":"/api/event/38001"}
```

Instead when I serialize the JSON it inserts extra '/' characters which is why I believe I am getting a 400 error:

```
{"leader":"John Smith","leader_id":"asldfkj234234324asldkfs234","resource_uri":"\/api\/event\/38001"}
```

Here is the code I am using.  Any ideas?

```
NSDictionary *myDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                self.clubToEdit.leader, @"leader",
                                self.clubToEdit.leaderID, @"leader_id",
                                @"/api/event/38001", @"resource_uri",
                                nil];

NSError *error; 
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:myDictionary options:0 error:&error];

if (!jsonData) 
{
    NSAssert(FALSE, @"Unable to serialize JSON from NSDict to NSData"); 
} else {
    NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    RKParams *params = [RKRequestSerialization serializationWithData:[jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]MIMEType:RKMIMETypeJSON];
    [client put:@"/api/event/?format=json&username=test&api_key=apikey" params:params delegate:self]; 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your question doesn't match the code. In your question, you state that you need to send `"\api\event\38001"` whereas in your code you write "`/api/event/38001"`. Since your question is only meaningful with the second case, I'll assume it to be effective.

Now the thing is that your JSON serializer class *escapes* the slashes (some special characters need escaping) and that's why it adds the backslashes before those characters.

Comment: Sorry, fixed the typo.  I guess my question still stands, how do I fix it? thanks

Comment: @RedRobin you don't meed to "fix" it.

Comment: Ok thanks, I guess something else is throwing the 400 error. thanks